# Sharepoint IF formula is returning the value NO

Tags: sharepoint-2010

The following Sharepoint formula is returning the value "NO", even though in the column [Average_1to3] the value is 5.3.  Wonder what I'm doing wrong?

I have to admit I've discovered that Sharepoint's common functions like If, And, Or, seem to follow the exact same syntax as Excel, so that's what I used.  A simpler IF formula I have (simply nesting 3 IF formulas without any And / Or statements) is working fine, using the same syntax.

```
=IF([Average_1to3]=1,"Low",IF([Average_1to3]=2.3,"Low Mod",IF(AND([Average_1to3]>=3.7,[Average_1to3]<=5.3),"Mod",IF(OR([Average_1to3]=6.7,[Average_1to3]=7),"Mod High",IF(OR([Average_1to3]=8.3,[Average_1to3]=10),"High")))))
```

Comment: In testing more, I'm starting to realize the formula may be correct, but may have to do with what SP is REALLY storing in fields where it displays simply "5.3".  Kind of sucks that I told it to store 1 decimal value, but underlying that it must be storing a higher precision that cannot be compared to (?)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in my local.

You could try to use some functions for troubleshooting, for example:

```
=EXACT([Average_1to3], "5.3")
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)

[image]